# php convert local time to utc time taking into consideration Daylight savings

Tags: php, mktime

suppose I have a certain date:

```
$date = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);
```

this date is in local time, now how can I convert it to utc time and store the new hour, minute ... in php variables similar to $hour, $minute ...

Comment: Do it using DateTime objects rather than unix timestamps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get UTC time with `gmdate`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

Also you can change your timezone to UTC: `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

Comment: it's giving the same result, even though there's a two hour difference between my local time and UTC

Comment: Than it means your server timezone is GMT.

Comment: can I change it to local time?

Comment: php.ini date.timezone directive. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone